# Unreasonable output generated by python-igraph closeness centrality

Tags: python, graph-theory, igraph, node-centrality

I am currently working on several graphs for generating their edge betweenness and node closeness, using python-igraph, setting as not directed, weighted, and having cut-off.

Edge betweenness could be acquired successfully. However, for closeness, the results can only be returned when no cut-off has been set; or the output would be 1 or NaN only. This issue happens regardless of the size and weight of the graph.

The following is one example graph.
[Please see the graph here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS0dQ.png)

I firstly created the edges dataframe by Pandas.

```
   u_index  v_index  length
0        0        1       1
1        0        2       1
2        0        3       2
3        0        4       3
4        1        2       1
5        3        4       2
```

Then create the graph based on information in the dataframe.

```
ntwrg = ig.Graph()
ntwrg.add_vertices(1+max(edges["u_index"].max(), edges["v_index"].max()))
ntwrg.add_edges(list(zip(edges["u_index"], edges["v_index"])))
ntwrg.es["length"] = edges["length"]
```

Then I started calculating centrality. When no cut-off, the results can be generated successfully:

```
ntwrg.closeness(weights="length")
```

```
    cls_cen
0  0.571429
1  0.444444
2  0.444444
3  0.400000
4  0.307692
```

However, when adding cutoff = 3, the expected result would be:

```
ntwrg.closeness(weights="length", cutoff=3)
```

```
    cls_cen
0  0.571429
1  0.600000
2  0.600000
3  0.400000
4  0.400000
```

While the result returned comes to be:

```
   Cls_cen
0      1.0
1      1.0
2      1.0
3      NaN
4      NaN
```

On the other side, edge betweenness can be generated normally even with cutoff=3:

```
ntwrg.edge_betweenness(weights="length", cutoff=3)
```

```
   Btw_cen
0      2.0
1      2.0
2      3.0
3      1.0
4      1.0
5      1.0
```

Comment: Could you explain why you expected these results for vertex closeness, when cutoff=3? A result of NaN is certainly expected in some cases if there are no paths of length shorter than 3, as path lengths are in the denominator so you don't want their sum to be 0.

Comment: Also, please note that it took me a very long while to read your post and understand your question. Your post would benefit by being rewritten in a much simpler way, with less code and more graph drawings, and less emphasis on pandas dataframes and more emphasis on the actual question you're asking.

Comment: *"As I have no knowledge about C language, I could not understand the logic behind this output."*  <<< I don't understand this sentence. What has the C language got to do with any of this?

Comment: Thanks @Stef for all the suggestions. I edited the text and link for the graph image of my example. You can see that in this case all the edges are within 3, so I believe in this case there wouls not be NaN case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** This was a bug in python-igraph 0.10.0 – 0.10.3.  It is fixed in 0.10.4.

---

This is a bug in python-igraph, [which I just fixed](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/commit/8c260e9c8a5305fce0e23b7ada7851aa9e2cc255). Thanks for pointing it out. The problem is present only in the Python interface of igraph, not in the igraph C library, or in other high-level interfaces of igraph.

Here is a transcript of checking this after the fix:

```
In [1]: import igraph as ig

In [2]: g = ig.Graph([(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(1,2),(3,4)])

In [3]: g.es['length']=[1,1,2,3,1,2]

In [4]: g.closeness(weights='length')
Out[4]: 
[0.5714285714285714,
 0.4444444444444444,
 0.4444444444444444,
 0.4,
 0.3076923076923077]

In [5]: g.closeness(weights='length',cutoff=3)
Out[5]: [0.5714285714285714, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4]
```

You can [compile the development version](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/#compiling-the-development-version) to get the fix immediately.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the issue. However, I come across an issue when getting the development version on Windows. How could I solve it?
  Building wheel for igraph (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Comment: @user21071448 If all goes well, there should be a new release with this fix within a few days.

Comment: Much appreciation for all your help. I would try the new version later.

Comment: @user21071448 The new release is now available.